# How to receive json data in python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am working on python flask, I came across a problem.
I want to send some specific data when I click on a button.
I am attaching the codes below.
All I want is inp data on start algo., other code flow is working fine.

```
function Started() {
      var inp = "Started"
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080" + "/apis/algo/start",
            type: "POST",
            data: inp,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Data submitted successfully....");
                alert(JSON.stringify(inp));
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Error while submitting Data");
            }
        });
      }
```

```
<button onClick="Started()">Start</button>
```

```py
class StartAlgoAPI(MethodView):
  def post(self):
    Inp_data = request.form.get('inp')
    print(Inp_data)
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Try `data: {inp: inp}`

Comment: You may need to specify `contentType: 'application/json'` on the `ajax` call too.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask, you can use `inp_data = request.get_json()` inside the function
As you have not included `@app.route` or similar in your excerpt, here is a link to a little tutorial you can find pretty quickly by using google
https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/01/07/flask-parsing-json-data/